# What's the best way to get a file from one computer on my network to another?

Tags: networking

I have a desktop, a laptop running ubuntu and an old box running ubuntu server with no gui or monitor. I need a reliable way to move files from the desktop and the laptop to the server. I am now SSHing into the server from the two client computers. Could I use that to transfer files, too? Should I set up some sort of ftp communication?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

> Just as all modern Unix-like systems have an SSH client, they also have SCP and SFTP clients. To copy a file from your computer to another computer with ssh, go to a command-line and type:
>
> ```
> scp thefile username@IP address or hostname:Destination
> ```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

Comment: Also look [into rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync).